# PHP setcookie() doesn't work on several pages

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I have some trouble understanding why `setcookie()` doesn't work on several pages.

```
if (isset($_POST['group'])){ 
    $group = stripslashes($_POST['group']);
    setcookie(GSgroup, $group, time()+3600);
}
```

I use the above code to set a cookie when a form is posted with several options. I use this on an included page so that all pages which use this function will set the cookie to the right group.

Now, this worked perfectly fine when I tried it on `localhost`, but after uploading it to a live website it doesn't work anymore. The strange thing is, that after I used it on another included page it did work.

Does anyone have any clue how this could be? I am really confused.

If you need more information please ask.

Comment: Is `GSgroup` a defined constant? Or is it a `string`? If it's a `string` you have to put quotes around it.

Comment: "It does not work" - great explanation of your problem, I'm contacting Charles Xavier to help me figure out what "does not work" means for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['group'])){ 
$group = stripslashes($_POST['group']);
setcookie(GSgroup, $group, time()+3600);
}
```

Is that the actual code? because the first parameter in the setcookie function should be a string or a variable containing a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
setcookie('GSgroup', $group, time()+3600);
```

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that cookies are loaded when the page loads, so if you set a cookie on line 5 in a PHP script with `setcookie` then accessing it with `$_COOKIE` on line 10 will not give you the cookie value.

You would need to reload the page to access the cookie value in this way.

I like [this](http://stut.net/2008/10/16/snippet-cookie-class-for-php/) PHP cookie class that has been made available.